# How to catch empty query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have several articles in my db and search on my site. if the user does not enter anything and click search, then displays all articles. How to catch empty request?

Code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die("Error");
mysql_select_db("selv_hram") or die("Error");
mysql_query('SET names "utf8"');

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = htmlspecialchars($searchq);      

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%' OR text_article LIKE '%$searchq%'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $output = '';

    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = 'Nothing find';
    }else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $text = $row['text_article'];
            $id = $row['id'];

            $output .= '<div>'.$title.' '.$text.'</div>';
        }
    }
}   
?>

    <div class="content-article">
        <form name="search" action="index.php" method="post" class="search-form">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" />
        <input type="submit" value=">>">
        <?php print("$output"); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by empty query ? You are already checking that `$row` is not empty with `$count`

Comment: Stop using **mysql_*** functions. They are obsolete and unsafe.

Comment: Use Javascript to make sure the search field has a value before the form is posted.

Comment: @PatrickQ never ever rely only on front-end validation. EVER.

Comment: @DainisAbols never ever assume that a comment is intended to be an all-encompassing answer to a question. EVER.

Comment: Use both javascript validation and php validation, plus like already said your query is open to sql injection, use something like PDO at least.

Comment: Was the data in your db encoded with `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: far too many answers below.

Comment: Thank you all! Everything works as it should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you read [this post about SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1),
change

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
```

to

```
if (!empty($_POST['search'])) {
```

Comment: Or just `!empty($_POST['search'])`

Comment: that can be narrowed down to a simple `!empty()` but your answer will work as per your original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37327273/1

Comment: You don't need isset() as empty() is designed to not throw errors if the variable does not exist.

Comment: Thanks - I changed it to `!empty($_POST['search'])`

Comment: you could have added to it, your original answer would also have been valid http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37327273/1

Comment: Why just isset? that won't check if the search has value

Comment: @DainisAbols `if (isset($_POST['search']) and strlen($_POST['search']) > 0)` as per [the original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37327273/1) is valid. I agree that just `isset()` isn't the best but it's still valid. `empty()` is better, yet using `strlen($_POST['search']) > 0)` is equivalent to checking if the POST is not empty. Quite a few other ways to go about it, but the answer has been edited.

Comment: I know, it was correct at start and got edited wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is simple validation.

```
if(empty($_POST['search'])) {
    echo "Empty search query"; 
} else {
    //search query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the user input first, if it is empty change the query. like below

```
 $searchq = htmlspecialchars($searchq);
 if(trim($searchq) == ''){
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");
 }else{
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%' OR text_article LIKE '%$searchq%'");
 }
```

Dont use depreciated mysql_ functions. Go for mysqli